# Maximo Anywhere - Take Photo - App Feature Issue

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I am trying to use "Take Photo" feature from iPad but am getting the below error on save. It takes photo properly and able to see the details of it in Anywhere while clicking submit,Issue begins.

I have made the configuration changes already in app-features.properties, build.properties also.

Error Log:

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /anywhereAttachment

java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /anywhereAttachment

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:528)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:127)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:88)

at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:215)

at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)

at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:220)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:968)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1056)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4553)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:301)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:266)

at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:776)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

 [project MaximoAnywhere]

SRVE0190E: File not found: /anywhereAttachment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that the Anywhere Attachment servlet (for some reason) did not deploy successfully when you deployed the MaximoAnywhere.ear into the MobileFirst Server.

Can you compare the web.xml from the MaximoAnywhere.war in your MaximoAnywhere/bin directory, to the web.xml in your running MobileFirst Server?  You should find some missing sections in the running MobileFirst server version.

Usually if they don't match, this is due to a MobileFirst behavior (bug?/feature?), where it strip/rewrite the web.xml if the MaximoAnywhere.war was built with a different version of the MobileFirst build libraries than the MobileFirst server.  We ship and document an exact version of MobileFirst server iFix to match our packaged MobileFirst build libraries to try and prevent this problem, but if your version of MobileFirst server is out of sync, it can still happen.

You can just cut and paste the missing info from the web.xml into your deployed MaximoAnywhere.war web.xml.

Comment: Scott, Thanks a lot for the quick response. I am using Worklight studio 6.3 for development. I can see the bin folder MaximoAnywhere.war file but could you please help me in getting the other file to compare. Thanks

Comment: Ah, in your Development Server, our Servlet doesn't automatically deploy.  You need to run a specific target in your build.xml (for my build level it's the enable-mobilefirst-studio-attachments target), and restart your MobileFirst Development Server.

Comment: did this work for you?  if not, can you grab the build output from that enable-mobilefirst-studio-attachments call, and we can take a look.

Comment: Scott, could you pl let me know what value need to give in "basedir" in build.properties(config.dir=${basedir}).Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are missing anywhere attachmentServlet deployment ,

Look for War in MaximoAnywhere.war in /bin directory , if you are using , websphere then you need to deploy this war part of websphere jvm.   look for your build.properties and check are you using local server or remote server and deploy correctly.